# Linhas e colunas em html

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Não estou conseguindo fazer com que as colunas fiquem na mesma linha, estou utilizando o código abaixo, porém as colunas saem uma do lado da outra, e quero que fique na mesma linha.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Você importou os estilos do bootstrap na pagina ?

Comment: Eu adicionei o código abaixo para importar o bootstrap

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css">

Comment: Mesmo com o Bootstrap não vai funciona com a classe col-4, tem que ser col-tamanho-numero (onde tamanho é lg, md, etc... e numero é o número de colunas que vc quer ocupar, de 1 a 12). Veja a minha resposta para entender melhor.

Comment: Você ta usando o bootstrap 4 ou o 3 ? para o 3 você precisa usar o indicador de tamanho col-md-3 ou outro tamanho, no 4 voce pode usar só col-3

Comment: @AnthraxisBR na tag da pergunta esta Bootstrap-3, mas inclui essa observação do BS3 ou BS4 na resposta de para deixar mais claro.

Comment: @hugocsl não prestei atenção nisso, positivei a resposta ali

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É porque vc está usando as classes do Grid de forma errada nas `<div>`

Não deve ser `col-4` deve ser assim: `col-md-4` *(onde está o MD, pode ser lg, md, sm, ou xs)*

Documentação oficial do Grid do Bootstrap3: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid

Dessa forma vai dar certo veja:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>algo aqui 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>algo aqui 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-4">
            <p>algo aqui 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**OBS:** No exemplo usei XS para sempre ficar em 3 colunas, mesmo em telas pequenas

---

Se vc estiver usando Bootstrap 4 vc pode usar as colunas apenas como col-4 mesmo. Nesse caso o seu problema seria com a indexação do Bootstrap na  da sua página.

Veja o Exemplo no Bootstrap4

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous" />

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <p>algo aqui 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Deu certo obrigada eu estou usando o Bootstrap 4 e não tinha indexado como na sua ultima resposta